# Laravel, check if data/record exists in any related table

Tags: database, model, laravel-5.1, relation

Maybe someone will help me.

DB structure:

```
users
id, name

storage_items
id, name, user_id

archive_objects
id, name, user_id
```

In User model i have:

```
public function storageItem()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StorageItem::class);
}

public function archiveObject()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ArchiveObject::class);
}
```

I need check if data/record exists in any related table.

Something like this:

```
if (User::has('storageItem')->orHas('archiveObject')->find(1)->count()) {
    //exists
}
```

This works:

```
if (User::has('storageItem')->find(1)->count()) {
    //exists
}
```

and this too:

```
if (User::has('archiveObject')->find(1)->count()) {
    //exists
}
```

but that are two queries, i need one beautiful query :)

As a result, i need that when i click button "Delete user", before deleting, i check if data/record exists in any related table, if true, it will show warning message about deleting related data/record (from storage_items or archive_objects), else it will delete just user (from users).

Comment: you can use trigger from the backend to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
User::where(function($query) { 
    $query->has('storageItem')
        ->orHas('archiveObject');
})->find(1);
```

Comment: Woohoo, thank you dude, it works perfectly! And ir more better than my own solution :D

$users = User::has('storageItem')->orHas('archiveObject')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();

if (in_array(2, $users )) {
    //exists
}

Answer (score 0):

try this `has` and `orWhereHas`

eg:

```
if (User::has('archiveObject')-orWhereHas('storageItem')->find(1)->count()) {
    //exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried another code

```
User::whereHas('archiveObject', function() {})->orWhereHas('storageItem', function() {})->find(2)
```

but it is similar with this

```
User::has('archiveObject')->orHas('storageItem')->find(2)
```

i have this result

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "created_at": "2016-02-05 11:45:12",
    "updated_at": "2016-03-20 15:12:15"
}
```

instead of this

```
{}
```

Result with "id": 1, i should have with this

```
User::has('archiveObject')->orHas('storageItem')->find(1)
```